# Better alternative to WAF path whitelisting?

Tags: web-application, firewalls, waf

We are managing a WAF which is being used by some applications. Recently I tried to use a Valid URL module to whitelist all the APIs and static resources of an application. Although from the security perspective it is good, I have to deal with the development team every day for opening new paths for them. It is kind of frustrating and needs a new changes to all environment every day.
I was thinking maybe it is not the best approach for using a WAF. 
Do you now any best practice for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure there is a 'best practice' as every organisation is different, however a very common practice in large enterprises is to use a combination of white and black-listing.

- For Dev environments you may just want to blacklist, because changes are very frequent.
- For Prod environments whitelist and lock down as much as you can. **And** blacklist known bad sites.

Where you have different applications in different DMZ's you can work on a risk-based and change-based mechanism and have some combination of the above, so that every firewall has a setup based on the profile needed.